# Remove main product image from child products of configurable products from product details page in magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, configurable-product, image

Why Magento2 is showing the Main products(Configured products) image in child product while choosing the option from the products details page. I don't want to show the main product image in the child image on option selection as shown in the screenshot.
In the first screenshot, I have marked the configured product with the red color arrow.
[image]

In the second screenshot you can see after option selection there are two images one is from a child product which is a simple product image and the other one is the main product image. Hence I want to eliminate that main product image after the option is selected.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to select "Hide from Product Page"

[image]

Don't forget to clear Magento cache after the change is made.

Comment: Hi I tried but placeholder image is showing i want to  eliminate it completely

Answer (score 0):

If someone else searches it.

The Luma Theme default value is prepend.

Replace “prepend” with “replace” for  gallery_switch_strategy

For that move to the below path
app\design\frontend\Themes\Yourtheme\etc\view.xml

Then, modify the code as follows

```
<vars module="Magento_ConfigurableProduct">
      <var name="gallery_switch_strategy">replace</var>
</vars>
```

[source](https://magecomp.com/blog/magento-2-hide-configurable-parent-image-when-swatch-selected/)